# pandas - Given two dataframe, remove differences

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following two dataframes: df1 and df2.
For each user, I want to remove the rows that contains itemids which do not appear in df2.

```
df1

userid itemid
  1       1
  1       3
  1       4
  2       1
  2       2
  2       3
  2       4


df2

userid itemid
  1       1
  1       2
  1       3
  1       4
  2       1
  2       2
  2       3
```

Since userid=1 in df1 has itemids 1,3,4 and userid=1 in df2 has itemids 1,2,3,4, I don't have to remove any rows from df1. However, for userid=2, df1 has itemids 2,3,4, while df2 has itemids 1,2,3. In this case, I want to remove the last row because itemid=4 is not in df2.
Therefore, the answer should be the following:

```
new_df1

userid itemid
  1       1
  1       3
  1       4
  2       1
  2       2
  2       3
```

Please note that df2 shouldn't change. I want only df1 to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with `left join` and `indicator` where was origin of rows.

Then filter by [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) and remove helper column by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
print (pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', indicator=True))
   userid  itemid     _merge
0       1       1       both
1       1       3       both
2       1       4       both
3       2       1       both
4       2       2       both
5       2       3       both
6       2       4  left_only

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', indicator=True)
       .query("_merge != 'left_only'")
       .drop('_merge',axis=1)
print (df)
   userid  itemid
0       1       1
1       1       3
2       1       4
3       2       1
4       2       2
5       2       3
```

Alternative solution with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', indicator=True)
df = df[df['_merge'] != 'left_only'].drop('_merge',axis=1)
print (df)
   userid  itemid
0       1       1
1       1       3
2       1       4
3       2       1
4       2       2
5       2       3
```